# Strange null-able member in derived WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following Winforms hierarchy.

```
Form ==> AForm ==> BForm
```

And there is a null-able member `int? X;` defined in `AForm`. And in `BForm`, there is the following code.

```
public partial class BForm : AForm, IBview
{
    ......
    public int Y
    {
        get
        {
            int z = X ?? 0;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("X: " + X.ToString() + " z: " + z.ToString());
            return z;
        }
    }
```

`X` shouldn't be null. I am trying to close and open the form `BForm`. It usually works and occasionally `z` is zero (maybe once every 10 times). I have a conditional break which is `z==0` on line `return z`.

When the break point is hit. The debug write

```
    X:  z: 0
```

But the value of `X` is neither null nor 0 when I hover the mouse cursor on `X` in visual studio after the break point is hit.

Comment: Silly question, is it plausible that the value of X is being explicitly assigned a `0` somewhere?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, no, not possible. X was null when the break point is hit.

Comment: @NickW: but you just said that when it hits, the value of `Y` is `0`, but `X` *is not `null`*. Isn't it?

Comment: But in your question you state: "the value of X is not null when I check".  So if `X` is null, `z` is 0; ALSO, if `X` is 0, `z` is also 0.  You have two conditions of `X` which can result in `z` being 0.

Comment: Be careful with conditional breakpoints, they can modify values if you type them wrong (i.e. accidentally write X = null instead of X == null or something).  Otherwise, do a find all references on X and put a breakpoint everywhere it gets modified.

Comment: @Tigran and ChrisSinclair I've updated the question to describe it more intuitively.

Comment: @BryceWagner The break point is good. I debugged with the break point after the weirdness is observed.

Comment: So, logically, if `z` is `0` but `X` is neither `0` nor `null`, then someone must have changed `X` while the `get` accessor was running, i.e. after the first code line of the `get` block and before the `return` statement. Is that possible? Are there multiple threads? Or are there events that might "fire" while you're executing the getter?

Answer (score 0):

If `X` is nullable - i.e. `int? X` - then, it's value is obtained via `X.Value`. You can also check:

```
int z = X.HasValue ? X.Value : 0;
```

Optionally, you may cast `X` - `(int)X` - but you would want to check if `X.HasValue` first. Otherwise, I believe you will get a null exception if X has not yet been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Initialization of BForm itself.  Just because BForm inherits values from AForm, that does not specifically mean that those values hold the physical value from other instances of AForm objects *Unless you set those values yourself*.

It has to do with how the BForm instance is created.  Something like this:

```
AForm A = new Aform(someValueForX);
BForm B = A;
```

OR

```
BForm B = new AForm(someValueForX);
```

in these cases, B.X would have the same value as A.X, and with the inheritance rules the assignment should be allowed.  But if X is not initialized somewhere in the declaration, then X will have no value for the specific instance of BForm you are looking at, even though it might have a value in some other instance of AForm.